# add 10 empty rows to gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i need that by default Gridview must have 10 empty rows with only one Column that column should have Textbox

here is my script of gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Others" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    onrowdatabound="gv_Others_RowDataBound" 
                    onrowcreated="gv_Others_RowCreated">
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40px">

                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtemp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

is that possible to create 10 empty rows by default in a gridview?

Comment: If you know how to add data to the girdview at all, then you can pass in some empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(string.Empty);
}
gv_Others.DataSource = list;
gv_Others.DataBind();
```

This is the quickest and dirtiest way I could think of, would I write something like this? No. But then I'm sure you have your reasons, would have been better if you'd written in your question what you were trying to achieve then we could have helped more and your question wouldn't have got marked down.

Comment: i need this because i want to insert mutiple values so now i can easily fatch all the values by looping through the Gridview rows and then can insert the values to Database Table.

Comment: another one.`var list = new List<string>(10); list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(String.Empty, 10));`

Answer (score 2):

```
you can try this 

 string[] str = new string[10]; 
 List lstStr = str.ToList<string>();
 gv_Others.DataSource = lstStr ;
 gv_Others.DataBind();
```